# How to find element with specific class attributes in selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium

On Windows Server 2012 I am using selenium 2.53.6, and I want to check if the `class` contains the element `lock-icon` for the following html element:

```
<a href="http://my.page/link/somewhere" class="more-link lock-icon" target="_blank">
                       Selenium Projekt dianep geheim
                   </a>
```

I tried the following expression with the python API:

```
find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="more-link.lock-icon")
```

but it returns a `None` although the element (shown above) is visible on the website.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="a.more-link")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try as below :-

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="a.lock-icon")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.lock-icon")
```

Hope it will work..:)

Answer (score 0):

Since `more-link` is also class name you should call it like `.more-link.lock-icon`.  See the following:

```
find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".more-link.lock-icon")
```